# How to use ffmpeg to detect sections with significant volume changes

Tags: ffmpeg, detection, volume

I'd like to use `ffconcat` to remove some very loud segments from mp3 files.
Here's a typical section as shown in Audacity:

[image: mp3 file with loud audio segment]

I should be able to use the `astats` filter to identify sections where the volume is significantly louder, but I couldn't figure out the correct syntax for **Windows** machines.

What `astats` filter parameters do I need to use to identify sections where the volume is significantly louder?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/615078/296803)? StackOverflow is mainly for programming, unlike SuperUser or Unix & Linux StackExchange sites where you can get help for CLI tools and other programs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I posted here, because there are actually several `ffmpeg` related posts. For example, [ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg).
If I don't get an answer here, I'll give the others sites a try.

Comment: take a look here https://superuser.com/a/1184012